# How to remove or replace a view modifier on a view in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to create a view modifier that takes a sound file as input and plays it on tap of the view.

```
struct AddSoundModifier: ViewModifier {
    var soundType: TapSoundType = .none

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture()
                .onEnded {
                    self.playSoundOnTap()
                })
    }
    
    private func playSoundOnTap() {
        SoundUtility.playBackgroundSoundWithUrl(soundType: soundType, bundle: nil, loopCount: 0)
    }
}
```

However, I also want to dynamically remove or change the sound in a different part of the code (essentially, I want the modifier to be uniquely applied for a view instance and override any previously applied modifier of the same type, in this case `AddSoundModifier` ), but I can't figure out how to store a reference to the previous view modifier or the gesture. In the objective-C world, I could use `objc_getAssociatedObject` and `objc_setAssociatedObject` to add functionalty in extensions, but is it possible in SwiftUI?

```
extension View {
    
    func addingSound(_ soundType: TapSoundType) -> some View {
        modifier(AddSoundModifier(soundType: soundType))
    }
}

Text("hello")
.addingSound(.primary)
.addingSound(.none) //This should cancel the previous modifier
```

Comment: `I want the modifier to be uniquely applied for a view instance` that's always true. So you example `Text.addingSound.addingSound` has `none` and not `primary`

Comment: @Dialogue Nope, replacement is not the default behaviour (at least from what I can see). I wished there was a way to do so. For example adding two `.padding` modifier adds both padding together. Even in this case, I just ran it in the playground replacing `SoundUtility.playBackgroundSoundWithUrl ` with a `print("playSoundOnTap")` statement and it prints the statement twice

Comment: Yes, it prints twice; that's correct. Because applies modifiers sequentially, but the final result will have `.none` when you gonna click

Comment: @Dialogue i think I'm missing something here. Are you saying if I add `.addingSound(.bells).addingSound(.whistles)` I'd only hear whistles? Because that is not what I'm observing. I am hearing bells and whistles

Comment: Oh, wait, it's not conditional, have missed that, then yeah, you might hear two sounds, just change it to conditional one

Comment: But the easiest way would be replacing `simultaneousGesture` with `.onTapGesture { self.playSoundOnTap() }` as you'll play twice anyway the same sound with `simultaneousGesture` and conditional `soundType`